# Uniform convergence of a series on the real line

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}$ and let $ g(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}  & x \ne0 \\
1 & x=0
\end{cases}$

Suppose $g$ is continious, bounded and have maximum at 0

Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g\cdot f_n(x)$ converges uniformly.

I've managed to show it for $x=0$ by using geometric sums and Weierstrass M-test, but I can't really find a way to show it for $x\neq 0$

Comment: For $x=0$ wouldn't $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g\cdot f_n(0)=e^{-n^2}\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ or am I wrong here?

Comment: I think the point is that it's strange (and kind of silly) to talk about uniform convergence at a single point.

Comment: Oh yeah thats probably right, I guess a sum that convergence in a single point, would converge uniformly in such a point (or how to put it). I was just thinking the approach would be to show uniform convergence for $x=0$,  $x<0$ and $x>0$

Comment: Already asked and already answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1799542/how-to-prove-the-inequality-frac1-e-x2x2e-x-n2-frac2n2/1799585#1799585